# Building Jenkins Config using SCM SYNC plugin

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I am using bitbucket to host my Jenkins config file. I have one question though. Does Jenkins pull latest config file everytime Jenkin is restarted from bitbucket or will it pull it from local stored configuration and use SCM for only version control?

Answer (score 0):

It works Viceversa. But

1. By default, SCM Sync plugin will check-in your local Jenkins changes to Bitbucket and keep it in sync with your local system (backup your changes)
2. if you want to retrieve/get changes from bitbucket you need to do manually "**Jenkins->configuration->SCM Sync configuration->Reload config from SCM**" manually then only you get backup from bitbucket account otherwise it's going to step 1 as it will keep your files safe in bit bucket